# Google DLP userdefined output for sensitive data

Tags: google-cloud-dlp

I'm having this request body for Google DLP as a text value. Is there any way to configure userdefined RedactConfig to modify the output..?. Is there any way to achieve that one..?

```js
{
  "item":{
    "value":"My name is Alicia Abernathy, and my email address is aabernathy@example.com."
  },
  "deidentifyConfig":{
    "infoTypeTransformations":{
      "transformations":[
        {
          "infoTypes":[
            {
              "name":"EMAIL_ADDRESS"
            }
          ],
          "primitiveTransformation":{
            "replaceWithInfoTypeConfig":{

            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "inspectConfig":{
    "infoTypes":[
      {
        "name":"EMAIL_ADDRESS"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there any way to configure userdefined RedactConfig to modify the output..?

And I need the following O/P from Google DLP.

```js
{
  "item": {
    "value": "My name is Alicia Abernathy, and my email address is {{__aabernathy@example.com__[EMAIL_ADDRESS]__}}."
  },
  "overview": {
    "transformedBytes": "22",
    "transformationSummaries": [
      {
        "infoType": {
          "name": "EMAIL_ADDRESS"
        },
        "transformation": {
          "replaceWithInfoTypeConfig": {}
        },
        "results": [
          {
            "count": "1",
            "code": "SUCCESS"
          }
        ],
        "transformedBytes": "22"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you don't actually want to anonymize text, you just want to add information to it? This API isn't suitable for that ... your best bet is to just use inspectContent and with the byte offsets in the findings do your own transforms.

Something like this in pseudocode ...

private static final void labelStringWithFindings(
      String stringToLabel,
      InspectContentResponse dlpResponse) {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    final byte[] messageBytes = ByteString.copyFromUtf8(
        stringToLabel).toByteArray();
    ImmutableList sortedFindings = 
        sort(dlpResponse.getResult().getFindingsList());

```
int lastEnd = 0;
for (Finding finding : sortedFindings) {
  String quote = Ascii.toLowerCase(finding.getQuote());
  String infoType = finding.getInfoType().getName();
  String surrogate = String.format("{{__%s__[%s]__}}",
      quote, infoType);
  final byte[] surrogateBytes = surrogate.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  int startIndex = (int) finding.getLocation().getByteRange().getStart();
  int endIndex = (int) finding.getLocation().getByteRange().getEnd();

  if (lastEnd == 0 || startIndex > lastEnd) {
    output.write(messageBytes, lastEnd, startIndex - lastEnd);
    output.write(surrogateBytes, 0, surrogate.length);
  }
  if (endIndex > lastEnd) {
    lastEnd = endIndex;
  }
}
if (messageBytes.length > lastEnd) {
  output.write(messageBytes, lastEnd, messageBytes.length - lastEnd);
}
return output.toString();
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your help.